# How to implement custom Caching in Retrofit (only for specific methods)

Tags: java, android, http, caching, retrofit2

I am wondering if there is a way to customize specific requests in retrofit whereas the rest one remains non-cacheable. Probably using a custom annotation:

```
@Cacheable
@GET("/user")
Call<UserResponse> getUser(@Path("id") String id);
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can initiaze retrofit like below for cached request and non-cached request

**For Caching**

```
    public static Retrofit initializeRetrofit(Context mContext) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        final File baseDir = mContext.getCacheDir();
        if (baseDir != null) {
            final File cacheDir = new File(baseDir, "HttpResponseCache");
            client.setCache(new Cache(cacheDir, 10 * 1024 * 1024));
        }

        //Setting time out for okHTTP
        client.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // connect timeout
        client.setReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.setRetryOnConnectionFailure(true);

        /**
         * For Logging in retrofit
         */
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        client.interceptors().add(interceptor);

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
```

**For Non Caching**

```
    public static Retrofit initializeRetrofitWithoutCache(Context mContext) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        //Setting time out for okHTTP
        client.setConnectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // connect timeout
        client.setReadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.setRetryOnConnectionFailure(true);

        /**
         * For Logging in retrofit
         */
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        client.interceptors().add(interceptor);

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
```

Use these functions to initializeRetrofit before making network call, use these functions as required in your api call function

You can do something like this to invoke your retrofit

**For Call with cache**

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = initializeRetrofit()
                .create(RetrofitInterface.class)
                .yourFunction(params...);
```

**For Call without cache**

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = initializeRetrofitWithoutCache()
                .create(RetrofitInterface.class)
                .yourFunction(params...);
```

You can also build a wrapper over it where you can define your routes and a flag to check caching is required or not

Comment: This is the default caching mechanism that does not allow to cache only specific request. I need a way to say retrofit to cache only this and this and this... requests

Comment: You can use these two functions to achieve this.

Comment: check my updated answer. You can do something like that to achieve that

Comment: This is not a good implementation. If you implement your application with layers, you know that the previous layers should not know the details of the underlying layer. With this implementation, the retrofit client should call different services regarding if the cache is supported or not. I need a single retrofit service without reveal the details details to the clients